# react-export-excel too slow on export

Tags: javascript, excel, reactjs

I'm trying to export a json to excel with the react-export-excel lib but it can only handle up to 3000/5000 rows. Once the rows number is greater than that it just freezes and won't return anything. I think my PC is probably one of the reasons but it's not that bad for this kind of operations.

```
<ExcelFile element={<button className="btn btn-outline-dark">Download Data</button>}>
    <ExcelSheet data={data} name='data'>
        <ExcelColumn label="cell" value="cell" />
        <ExcelColumn label="dog" value="dog" />
        ...
    </ExcelSheet>
</ExcelFile>
```

Comment: At my previous job we had to export files with more than 200k rows. To solve the issue with freezing we used web workers. Basically the webworker is a parallel thread to your main thread (so your browser won't freeze). In the worker we generated the blob and sent it as response to the main thread. Then the browser could just use the blob and create an excel file. Look into webworkers.

Comment: or send the data to the backend, transform the data to a ".csv" or ".xls" and download it from the frontend